# How can I save sensor data in mysql?

Tags: python, mysql, bluetooth, phpmyadmin, arduino

My raspberry pi receive sensor data from arduino via bluetooth. And I want to save sensor data in mysql. This is code using python

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import bluetooth
import MySQLdb

bd_addr="(Mac address)"
port=1
sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFOMM)
sock.connect((bd_addr.port)))
data=""

db=MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "user", "pwd", "db")
curs=db.cursor()
while 1:
  try:
      data +=sock.recv(1024)
      data_end=data.fint('\n')
      if data_end!=-1:
        rec=data[:data_end+1:]
        print data
        data=data[data_end+1]
        strQuery="INSERT INTO table (kg) VALUES ('+data')"
        curs.execute(strQuery)
        db.commit()
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    break
sock.close()
db.close()
```

And when I run this code, I can read sensor data correctly, but in mysql 
different data is saved.
If I insert localhost/phpmyadmin and check my db only '0' is existed. And this is my terminal. What is my problem?

```
11.70
mysql.py:25: Warning: Incorrect doubl value: '+data' for column 'kg' at row 1 curs.execute(strQuery)
11.78
11.72
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Python application sends the SQL statement `INSERT INTO table (kg) VALUES ('+data')` to your database, where the database will try to write the string `+data` into the column `kg`.

What you probaly wanted to do:

```
strQuery="INSERT INTO table (kg) VALUES (" + str(data) + ")"
curs.execute(strQuery)
```

even better:

```
strQuery="INSERT INTO table (kg) VALUES ({})".format( data )
curs.execute(strQuery)
```

or if you want to use sql bindings:

```
strQuery="INSERT INTO table (kg) VALUES (?)"
curs.execute(strQuery, (data,)) # here you pass the value(s) as iterable parameter
```

Comment: if I follow your answer there is an error. Start Monitor
0.19

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mysql.py", line 25, in <module>
    curs.execute(strQuery,)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 226, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1136, "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1")


------------------
(program exited with code: 1)
Press return to continue

Comment: Looks as if you wrote ``curs.execute(strQuery,)`` in your application. If you do not use SQL bindings, you should remove the comma. If you use SQL bindings, you need to provide an iterable with your values. I updated my answer to reflect that.